# What's the name of this french song by Dalida?

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics

I've been looking for the name of [this Dalida's song](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_9vCAvXd5kckotMDNWZjFhRDQ/view?usp=sharing) for two hours and because I don't know French, it's a very hard job.
Can you please tell me its name?
I want to find its lyrics and their translation in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The English version of this song is best known as "[Those Were the Days](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3KEhWTnWvE)."  It was a huge hit in 1968 for Mary Hopkins.  The French version is called "[Le Temps des Fleurs](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/Le-Temps-Des-Fleurs-flowers-time.html)," ("The Time of Flowers") and both versions are adaptions of an old Russian song called "[Dorogoi Dlinnoyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Those_Were_the_Days_%28song%29)" ("By the Long Road"). There are also versions in Spanish ("Que Tiempo Tan Feliz"), German ("An Jenem Tag") and Italian ("Quelli Erano Giorni").

Please also note that the different versions are NOT just strict translations of each other --there is considerable variation in the meanings.

> Once upon a time there was a tavern
> Where we used to raise a glass or two
> Remember how we laughed away the hours
> And dreamed of all the great things we would do

> Those were the days my friend
> We thought they'd never end
> We'd sing and dance forever and a day
> We'd live the life we choose
> We'd fight and never lose
> For we were young and sure to have our way.
> La la la la...
> Those were the days, oh yes those were the days

> http://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/mary+hopkin/those+were+the+days_20317307.html

Answer (score 8):

It's called *Le Temps des Fleurs*.

You can find an English translation here : http://lyricstranslate.com/en/Le-Temps-Des-Fleurs-flowers-time.html